# Error on passing variable on the function xp_dirtree

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a stored procedure that gathers the names of all of the files located in a specific archive and stores it in a temp table. When I write it and hardcode the path as a param in the function xp_dirtree, it yields the results I wanted.

```
IF ( SELECT Object_id('tempdb..#archf_names')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #archf_names
END

--table to hold file information
CREATE TABLE #archf_names(filename VARCHAR(MAX), depth INT, filetype INT NOT NULL)     

INSERT #archf_names (filename, depth, filetype)
EXEC MASTER.sys.xp_dirtree '\\sqlvm82\ImportsExports\Archive\Archive', 1, 1

SELECT * FROM #archf_names
WHERE filetype <> 0
```

When I try to pass in a variable of type VARCHAR that has been set to equal the same path that was hardcoded above, I get this error "
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded."

```
DECLARE @path  AS VARCHAR(MAX) --Path to folder containing archive

SET @path = 'C:\\sqlvm82\ImportsExports\Archive\Archive'

IF ( SELECT Object_id('tempdb..#archf_names')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #archf_names
END

IF ( SELECT Object_id('tempdb..#sh_out')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #sh_out
END

CREATE TABLE #sh_out(line VARCHAR(MAX)) -- table for xp_cmdshell output
CREATE TABLE #archf_names(filename VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, depth INT NOT NULL, filetype INT NOT NULL) --table to hold file information

INSERT #archf_names (filename, depth, filetype)
EXEC MASTER.sys.xp_dirtree @path, 1, 1
SELECT * FROM #archf_names
WHERE filetype <> 0
```

There are some other functionalities that are a part of this stored proc but the snippets above are the ones I'm having a problem with. I hope I explained myself clearly enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try not using a LOB type for the parameter. Does your `@path` really need to support 2 billion characters? Changing your `DECLARE` to this works fine for me (and it does return valid data, not "blank columns"):

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(8000);
```

Comment: That fixed the error I was having, but now instead of giving me the expected results I just get blank columns. Is there any particular reason why MAX gives that function such an issue?

Comment: Because `xp_dirtree` was written long before the `MAX` types were even introduced, and - as it is an unsupported and undocumented stored procedure that shouldn't be used - they don't need to maintain its compatibility as new versions of SQL Server come out? If you want something to rely on going forward, please write your own CLR mechanism for accessing the file system. There are dozens of example libraries out there you can just grab or modify.